# Оставить кнопку активной в неактивной expansion panel summary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

При получении ответа с сервера я в цикле формирую expansion panels, активность которых определяется тем, что пришло в ответе.

```
response = [
    {
      someKey: someValue,
      disabled: true //тут
    },
    {
      someKey: someValue, 
      disabled: false //тут
    }
]
response.map((item) => {
           return (
              <ExpansionPanel disabled={item.disabled)}>
                    <ExpansionPanelSummary>                        

                     //данная кнопка должна быть активна всегда,
// но если item.disabled = true, она находиться в неактивной панели и тоже неактивна 
                      <Button>сделать хорошо </Button>
                    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                </ExpansionPanel>
        )

    }
})
```

Как сохранить кнопку активной? можно ли как-то вынести её из панели, не потеряв стили отображения или как-то игнорировать активность контейнера? кнопка играет роль контекстного меню и перенести его в другой элемент панели не представляется возможным.

Comment: Сделать элемент активным внутри задизейбленного родителя не получится просто так. Так как компонент вложенный, даже если написать в аттрибут кнопки `disabled={false}` - это не поможет, так как родитель весь задизейблен. Самый простой вариант - вынести кнопку из дизейбленного родителя, но придется возиться с разметкой. Второй вариант - немного сложнее. Написать свои классы, который при наличии у родителя класса на дизейбл (имя класса, а не аттрибут) - будут добавлять некое поведение, отключающее клики и ввод, к примеру `pointer-events:none;`. Но это костыль, поэтому первый вариант - выносить.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, подтвердили опасения